# Django: How can i get the sections of pdf file and jump to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I develop a simple site in django.
in this site the user has to upload a pdf file,
and then he can see it with tree of sections in the side.
The challenge is:
A. How can i read the file sections?
it could be in django, python, javascript or each another idea.
B. How can i jump to specific section when the user click on it?

I display the file with html object tag.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure, that I understand you correctly, but if you talk about Named Destinations in PDF file you should:

- get Named Destinations of PDF file with pyPdf library with "getNamedDestinations" method
- open PDF file with nameddest parameter like "http://example.org/doc.pdf#nameddest=something"